# Metro App global variables C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Im creating my first app for Windows 8 and i have a question. In Windows Phone 7 we can define in App.xaml.cs all global variables and access by App.all_performers for exemple, this works fine with default data types but if i create a List of one object created by me like evento

```
public static List<evento> eventos_near = new List<evento>();
```

i have this error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<UrbaneousTry2.evento>' is less
>   accessible than field 'UrbaneousTry2.App.eventos_near'

Anyone can help me? i need Lists and Dictionaries to use in all pages of my app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are hitting is that `evento` isn't a public type yet you've declared it as available in a public location.  If this were legal it would allow a type declared to be not public be accessible from any referencing assembly which effectively makes it public.

You need to either switch `evento` to be a public type or make the declaration internal

```
internal static List<evento> eventos_near = new List<evento>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your class `eventos` public.

Comment: The `eventos_near` declaration is the field while `evento` is the type